# CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IExtensibleDataObject' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.Serialization'

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I had added a wsdl as service reference in my project and I got the following error when my code is moved on hosting server it executes fine on local server..

> **Compilation Error**
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'IExtensibleDataObject' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File: App_WebReferences.fcpcl-q0.0.cs    Line: 20
>
> **Show Detailed Compiler Output:**
>
> **Show Complete Compilation Source:**
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4241;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4223

So if anyone knows the answer please help to sort out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run VS 2013 and had the same problem. My code contained "using System.Runtime.Serialization", but when I added  System.Runtime.Serialization as a project reference, the message disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

[IExtensibleDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was added in .NET 3.0. Does the hosting server have .NET 3.0 or later? From the version in your questions, it looks like it might not.

Comment: my hosting server setting have been set on this framework version 2.0-3.0-3.5.  the error is in the code that generated after wsdl compiled